# How to copy elements to a Vector if you are given a pair of iterators?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to find a way to copy elements of a vector to another vector.

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> aVec{0,1,2,3,4};
  std::vector<int>::iterator itBegin = aVec.begin();
  std::vector<int>::iterator itEnd = aVec.begin()+3;

  std::vector<int> aVecNew;
  // How to insert elements ranging from itBegin till itEnd(including itEnd) to
  // the vector aVecNew

  return 0;

}
```

Most of the insert methods appear not to include itEnd. Is there a clean way to do this?

EDIT: If I am not sure ++itEnd is the end iterator or not. In such case it would fail.  Is there any safer way without the mess ?

Comment: just increment the end iterator to: `std::vector<int>::iterator itEnd = aVec.begin()+4;` and use whichever _vector member method (function)_ you want. For example: `aVecNew.assign(itBegin, itEnd);`

Comment: if ++itEnd yielded the end iterator; what "mess" would you fear? That would just be the standard case of copying the whole vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::copy` from `<algorithms>` and `std::back_inserter` from `<iterator>`:

```
int main(int a, char**){
  std::vector<int> aVec{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  std::vector<int>::iterator itBegin = aVec.begin();
  std::vector<int>::iterator itEnd = aVec.begin() + 3;

  std::vector<int> aVecNew;
  std::copy(itBegin, itEnd, std::back_inserter(aVecNew));
  return 0;
}
```

PS: Also, as it was mentioned in the comment, this code copies excluding itEnd. If you want to copy elements including itEnd, just increment its value by 1:

```
int main(int a, char**){
  std::vector<int> aVec{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  std::vector<int>::iterator itBegin = aVec.begin();
  std::vector<int>::iterator itEnd = aVec.begin() + 3;

  std::vector<int> aVecNew;
  std::copy(itBegin, ++itEnd, std::back_inserter(aVecNew));
  return 0;
}
```

Some documentation on [back_inserter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/) and [copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/).

Comment: The user wants to copy `[itBegin, itEnd]` where this copies `[itBegin, itEnd)`

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the ways already mentioned, `std::vector` has a constructor that will do exactly what you want (take the elements from range given begin and end iterators).

```
std::vector<int> aVecNew(itBegin, ++itEnd);
```

Comment: If I am not sure ++itEnd is the end iterator or not. In such case it would fail.  Is there any safer way without the mess ?

Comment: The end iterator typically points to the element after the last element, so you are not allowed to increment the iterator if it points to the end of the container. I just put the ++ in front of itEnd, because you told as you would like to copy including the element itEnd points to. A better way however, would be to keep with the "after the last element" style and set `itEnd = aVec.begin() + 4` so you specify the range in the same way all standard algorithms (and containers) do.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case - the target vector does already exist - the [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) onto a [back_insert_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) until just before `++itEnd`  is the right way, but in your case,

```
std::vector<int> aVecNew(itBegin, ++itEnd);
```

is the appropriate measure. [`std::vector` has ctor #(4)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)   for that; no reason to first create and then populate the `vector` here.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>     // ostream_iterator
#include <algorithm>    // copy

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> aVec{0,1,2,3,4}; // this is c++ of 2011 or later...

    // ... thus this 
    std::vector<int>::iterator itBegin = aVec.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator itEnd = aVec.begin() + 3;
    // (if used) would at least be a case for "auto" 

    std::vector<int> aVecNew(itBegin, ++itEnd);

    std::copy(aVecNew.begin(), aVecNew.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); 

    std::cout << std::endl; 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output:

```
0 1 2 3
```

**[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9aef73ffff6a7b04) at Coliru's**